# R histogram graph (ggplot) "floating" above x-line

Tags: r, ggplot2

My histogram looks like this:

[image]

With respective code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Value, color=Type, fill=Type))+ 
  geom_histogram(position="Identity", alpha=0.5)+
  xlab("Loss in MN$")+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_vline(data=mean, aes(xintercept=grp.mean),
             linetype="dashed")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#E52B2B", "#2BE531", "#2BE531"))+
  labs(title="Scenario 1 - Loss Distribution with 1000 different recovery days", subtitle = "Scenario description see text")
```

I would like to get rid of the gap between the x-axis and the y=zero value.
This never occurred to me before.

I've tried to do so with ylim(...) but this is not applicable to histograms.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: try with `scale_y_continuous(expand =  expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))`

Comment: To explain @Peter comment slightly, by default ggplot takes the nominal data ranges and adds a small amount of padding, or a buffer. Normally this is the best option, to avoid abrupt cutoffs at the edges, but you can remove them, as noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `scale_y_continuous(expand =  expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=qsec))+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05)))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>